# Find model type of a strongly-typed razor view (or any view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I find the model type of a (razor) view from the controller? I know they inherit from WebViewPage and WebViewPage, and that's about it.

(In asp.net c# MVC 3 or 4)

Thanks in advance.

Edit- use case:
Allowing a user to create/upload/edit views and strongly typed views, then user can pick one of those user created views to display/edit different types of data in the database.

So for example, the application retrieves an object Foo, and there are Views strongly typed for Boo and Foo. I don't want views for Boo to show up as possible selection for Foo objects.

Comment: If you do this you need to be aware of the security implications of allowing a user to upload and run arbitrary code on your server.

Comment: Hi yes I'm perfectly aware. It's not a "public upload" but rather an internal process where the stake holder work with the internal dev to provide the content managers the views to pick from. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you would want to do this, but you could just do

```
@Model.GetType()
```

You should try to avoid as much code in your view as possible and push the logic into your controller or services.

Comment: Updated question. What I want to do is allow users to associate different views to an object. However, I don't want them to associate views to object that doesn't have the correct model type for.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why cant you just say something like...`if(type)return View("typeView",obj);else return View(obj);` Maybe you can provide a better example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a `IEnumerable<WebViewPage<T>>`, you can get the type of `T` by doing the following:

```
// Assuming 'views' is a IEnumerable<WebViewPage<T>> here.
var validFooViews = views.Where(v =>
    v.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(Foo));
```

Comment: In your question you mentioned that the user could pick from a list of user-created views, so I assumed you had access to this data. In my example, I am simply assuming 'views' is an `IEnumerable<WebViewPage<T>>` defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the case. The views are uploaded and deployed by developers as cshtml.